# How to use pst-asr package on a Mac

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr,graphicx}\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}

\begin{document}

\asr bɪt \endasr

\end{document}
```

Hi, I am trying to use "pst-asr" package. I added the package in the preamble, but I keep getting "undefined control sequence."

I've checked that pastricks, pst-asr, and graphicx has been installed with TeX Live Utility (I'm using a Mac OS X), but can't find pst-xkey.

Any advice, please?

Comment: The `pst-asr` package uses `pstricks` and must be compiled with either `latex+dvips` or `xelatex` (not `pdflatex`). Try adding `% !TEX TS-program = latex` as the first line of your document (if your editor recognizes that directive.)

Comment: Hi, Alan. Thanks for the advice. I use TeXStudio, but it doesn't seem to recognize the directive.

Comment: Try just `% !TeX program = latex`. Does that work?

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't work.

Comment: It really should be installed. What does `kpsewhich pst-xkey.sty` or `locate pst-xkey.sty` return? (I'm pretty sure these commands also work on OSX.)

Comment: It returns: "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/pst-xkey.sty" and "WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist." respectively.

Comment: No the problem is with TeXStudio.  You can get your document to compile using the Tools -> Commands -> LaTeX menu item, and then subsequently choosing DVI-PS and then PS-PDF.  I'm not sure how to tell TeXStudio to automate this, however. If you go to the preferences and choose the DVI-PS-PDF build chain for Build and View, then the Build-View menu button will do everything for you.

Comment: Awww..I got "/usr/texbin/dvips: DVI file can't be opened: System Report.dvi: No such file or directory" for DIV-PS.