# Troubles with pst-asr on a Mac

Tags: pstricks, texshop, linguistics, pst-asr

I can't make the `pst-asr` package on my Mac. I know that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227138/how-to-use-pst-asr-package-on-a-mac) someone had a similar issue, but I really don't know what to do with those directions - sorry for my ignorance, I hope someone can help. :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
\usepackage{pst-asr}

\begin{document}

\asr karl \endasr

\end{document}
```

Comment: While you were typing, I was just update the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pst-asr` package uses PSTricks, and usually needs to be compiled using `latex+dvips` (it can possibly also work with XeLaTeX).

Since you are using TeXShop, you can simply add

```
% !TeX program = latex
```

to the first line of your source document.  You can also get TeXShop to add this line for you by placing your cursor at the top and choosing the Program item from the Macros menu. This will present you with a list of the available TeXShop engines. In this case, choose the one that says `latex`.

Comment: alright - my bad. I'm deleting this post. Sorry for double posting.

Comment: @RobertP. No, don't delete this one, since it now has an answer, and the other one never really got resolved. I can turn my comments into an answer there too, but it's fine to have a duplicate for the moment.